# Revit API: how to put revit links to Combobox

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm new to Revit API. And I can't see the Revit links from the Method in the ComboBox.

```cs
public static IList<Document> GetAllRevitLinkInstances(ExternalCommandData commandData)
{
    UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
    UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
    Document arDoc = uidoc.Document;
    FilteredElementCollector collector = new 
    FilteredElementCollector(arDoc);
    collector.OfClass(typeof(RevitLinkInstance)).ToList();
    IList<Document> linkedDocs = new List<Document>();
    foreach (Element elem in collector)
    {
        RevitLinkInstance instance = elem as RevitLinkInstance;
        Document linkDoc = instance.GetLinkDocument();
        linkedDocs.Add(linkDoc);
        // linkedDocs.Add(string.Format("{0}.rvt", 
        linkDoc.Title.ToString()));
        //linkedDocs.AppendLine("FileName: " + Path.GetFileName(linkDoc.PathName));
        //RevitLinkType type = arDoc.GetElement(instance.GetTypeId()) as RevitLinkType;
        //linkedDocs.AppendLine("Is Nested: " + type.IsNestedLink.ToString());
    }

    return linkedDocs;
}
```

In MVVM I use:

```cs
public Document SelectedLinkedInstances { get; set; }
public IList<Document> LinkedInstances { get; } = new List<Document>();

public MainViewViewModel(ExternalCommandData commandData)
{
    _commandData = commandData;
    SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSaveCommand);
    LinkedInstances = LinkUtils.GetAllRevitLinkInstances(commandData);
}
```

But in the ComboBox finally I see only empty lines. So, the docs are not seen in the ComboBox. May be someone faced the same problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TndNq.png)

Comment: Please provide more code information.  Is this Winforms or WPF?  How is the Combobox connected to your data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have two main issues. I've not seen `.ToList()` for the `FilteredElementCollector` class before, you probably want `.ToElements()` - that gives you an `IList<Element>` [ToElements RevitAPIDocs](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/732b4a0d-62d8-b86d-120b-8ea3d9713b34.htm)

You also don't have the XAML (Assuming some things here) shown. Check to see that you're binding that list into the window correctly. I typically set the item source in the code so something simple like:

```
LinkedInstances = LinkUtils.GetAllRevitLinkInstances(commandData);    
LinkedDocsComboBox.Items = LinkedInstances;
```